# Excel VBA Do While loop opening most recent workbook infinite loop

Tags: vba, while-loop

I'm quite new to VBA and in my code I am going through a file path to open the most recent file however I seem to be getting an infinite loop. For context the workbook only generate twice a month hence why I am trying to reverse back from current day. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

```
Dim strToday As String
Dim strFileName_CBM As String
Dim b As Integer

'Selecting the correct reporting date
strToday = Format((Now()), "YYYY-MM-DD")

 b = 0

 strFileName_CBM = "\Administration\Finance\Reports\Portfolio\Current_Book_Monthly_" & _
                     Format(CDate(strToday) - b, "YYYY-MM-DD") & ".xlsx"

 Do While Dir(strFileName_CBM) = ""
    If Dir(strFileName_CBM) = "" Then
        strFileName_CBM = "\Administration\Finance\Reports\Portfolio\Current_Book_Monthly_" & _
                     Format(CDate(strToday) - b, "YYYY-MM-DD") & ".xlsx"
    End If
 b = b - 1
Loop
```

Comment: Did you mean `b = b + 1` ?

Comment: Thanks for the responses but Tim's solution was the issue. I was playing around and noticed my date's were increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (though your path looks a bit incomplete...)

```
Sub Tester()
    Const MAX_PERIOD As Long = 100
    Dim b As Long

    b = 0

    'look back up to 100 days
    Do While Len(Dir(FileName(Date - b))) = 0 And b < MAX_PERIOD 
        'Debug.Print FileName(Date - b)
        b = b + 1
    Loop

    If b = MAX_PERIOD  Then
        'no file found
        MsgBox "No file found newer than " & MAX_PERIOD & "  days"
    Else
        'open the file
        Workbooks.Open FileName(Date - b)
    End If

End Sub

'construct file path & name from date
Function FileName(dt)
    FileName = "\Administration\Finance\Reports\Portfolio\Current_Book_Monthly_" & _
                     Format(dt, "YYYY-MM-DD") & ".xlsx"
End Function
```